# Measuring light from two distant light sources in the middle

Tags: speed-of-light

I am trying to get some understanding of next scenarios.

Suppose we have three objects: Light source 1, Light source 2 and observer. LS1 and LS2 both emit a single photon each second with the same energy.

They are spaced like so:

(LS1)-----------------(O)-----------------(LS2)

Can you please confirm or reject my expectations of the next scenarios.

**Scenario 1:**
Nobody moves.

The observer will detect photons coming from sources, every second with the same energy.

**Scenario 2:**
Either LS moves away\towards observer with constant speed.

The observer will measure photons every second, but energy will be red\blue shifted depending on direction of LS.

**Scenario 3:**
Observer moves towards LS2 with high speed

Light from LS1 will be red shifted.
Light from LS2 will be blue shifted.
Time interval between each photon will still be 1 second regardless of direction of the observer move direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your photons can be visualized as moving on the crest of a very long wave. Their time and distance spacing will be subject to the same Doppler formulas which explain the color shifts that you describe.

Comment: I have some problems visualizing this? Is it like a spherical wave from the center of the source (e.g. LS1)?

Comment: Yes, it would need to be a wave from the moving source.